# Fading problems with Cufon elements on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fonts, cufon

I have a slideshow running with textquotes. These quotes contain a custom font provided by cufon. This all works fine.
However when the slideshow fades in or out, the text gets a dark border or shadow. I think its a transparancy issue in IE but I can't find a solution.

I'm using the jQuery plugin Cycle for my slideshow, and it has some IE opacity and cleartype fixes but none work.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered using @font-face instead of Cufon? (http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: I've used that in the past but unfortunately a lot of fonts simply do not work in alle browser when using @font-face. I've had sites where all fonts worked in chrome, one worked in FF and in IE the other other one worked. Cufon is far more reliable in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but because people might still end up here when searching for similar issues, I'd like to add the "solution".

De solution is quite simple really. Use @font-face. Just like Mottie suggested. I ended up switching to a different but very similar font that did not have the beforementioned issues with @font-face.

As far as I can tell it's not possible to fix it by use of cufon in any way that does not involved seeing flickering texts or any other rendering issue.